# UTF to ASCII Conversion

Tags: java, web-services, unix, ascii, utf

I am using Java web service to call an oracle procedure to read some records. The executing of this Java web service is automated with the help of Shell Script. 
So the flow is like:

Shell scripts calls the Java Web service, further Java web service calls the Oracle stored procedure to read some records.

As an end product a feed file is generated which is in UTF-8 format and we need our file to be created in ASCII. So could any one help me with some Linux or Java code which I could add to my shell script or Java code to convert the file to ASCII.

P.S. I am aware about converting the file from UTF to ASCII with help of NOTEPAD++, but i need this process to be automated. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is UTF -8 . Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: It is worth noting that if all of your text consists of ASCII characters, a UTF-8 file *is* an ASCII file.  (UTF-8 is deliberately designed for such compatibility.)  If it contains non-ASCII characters, then those characters will likely be converted to `?`.  You might be able to preserve some of them by first [compatibility-normalizing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html#NFKC) the text.

Comment: Echoing @VGR, you might want to re-validate the requirement that says get text from the database and obliterate some characters with question marks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with this:

```
Charset srcEncoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
Charset destEncoding = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII;
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("src"), srcEncoding);
     BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("dest"), destEncoding)) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.write(line);
        writer.newLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for `Charset.forName`; both of those are in [StandardCharsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html).

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution depends on how you are currently writing the file.
There are plenty of methods.
If you are working with bytes you could use:

```
byte[] bytes = "somestring".getBytes("characterSetName");
```

The [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)) method contains a character set name in the constructor:

```
new PrintStream(file,"characterSetName");
```

In your case the character set name would be [US-ASCII](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

You could also use Charset instances to convert between character sets.

As an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String textToWrite = "Hello World of encodings...";
    CharBuffer cb1 = CharBuffer.wrap(textToWrite);
    CharBuffer cb2 = CharBuffer.wrap(textToWrite);

    Charset chr = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = chr.encode(cb1);
    write("CharsetEncode.txt",byteBuffer);

    CharsetEncoder cr = chr.newEncoder();
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer1 = cr.encode(cb2);
    write("CharsetEncoderEncode.txt",byteBuffer1);

    write("StringGetBytes.txt",textToWrite.getBytes("US-ASCII"));

}

public static void write(String name, ByteBuffer buffer) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.limit()];
    buffer.get(bytes);
    write(name,bytes);
}

public static void write(String name, byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(name);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
```

When making use of a BufferedWriter, you could use [Files.newBufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)). This allows the specifying of the character set.

```
File targetFile = ....;
BufferedWriter w = Files.newBufferedWriter(targetFile.toPath(), Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
```

Comment: Hey, What will be the value of Somestring if converting from UTF-8 to ASCII?

Comment: Like stated, US-ASCII.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read that part, what about somestring? Is it the file name which is generated or the type of file which is generated ?

Comment: "somestring" is the text or contents of the file. The most obvious solution would be to write the file in the correct encoding in the first place in stead of converting later on.

Comment: So if i want it to write it in ASCII format rather than UTF in the first place, then whats the best way to do it. Right now i am using the Byte to write the file and it automatically writes it into UTF-8 format.

Comment: How are you getting those bytes? From a String?

Comment: I am creating a blank string first, then reading the data from the database by calling stored procedure and once I get the record, i update it in the blank string and further write it to the file using write buffer and it is generating the file as UTF-8.

Comment: What class is the writebuffer? does it accept byte[]? if so convert the string to ascii and write those bytes. Or does the write buffer perhaps support setting a specific character set?

Comment: java.io.BufferedWriter  is the class !!

Comment: See the updated section about Files.newBufferedWriter